# Make a jpg file in vector graphic

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, image-quality

I have an jpg. with 72 dpi. How can I make this with better quality. 
It is a logo from a company. Who wanted the logo on a flag.
I vectorized in Inkscape(sorry for that all your Adobe specialist).
I send it to the company, who would do the work, but they are not satisfied.

A: Can I use photoshop to change the picture to 300dpi better quality, and then vectorized it?
B: Can i use Illustrator(I have cs4 at home) to do draw or some how digitize it, and save it as an eps file?

I'am a little bit frustrating. Please Help.

Morten

Comment: DPI/PPI is completely irrelevant for Vectors. 
Why were they unhappy?

Comment: It's difficult to turn a crappy (pixelated or blurry) graphic into a clean one by magically washing it with tools in graphics programs, unless the problems are very simple. In almost all cases, the proper method is to re-create the art from scratch using vectors and fonts and the correct color specifications. They may want to hire a production artist/graphic designer who can create printable files based on the logo. Trying to manipulate the crap out of crap usually just produces more crap.

Comment: "*...they are not satisfied.*' -- Why???

Comment: If you vectorized the image in Inkscape, then why didn't you send them the SVG file? Why are they not satisfied. A jpeg is not a vector format. This question need more details. Please edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Illustrator to *manually* rework a logo from JPG to vector format (AI generally, but EPS too if you must), then save it back into JPG at 300dpi. Please note this is *not* an automatic process and you actually need to know how to use Illustrator to create vector logos.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand two things.

I. The PPI does not mean anything, absolutely anything in this case. 72, 300 or 1000. Your JPG file is simply small size. Period.

> to 300dpi better quality

No. that will not magically appear lost information. The point here is information, not quality.

II. Does the company really care about its branding? About their visual identity?
If they do, they need to stop sending small JPG images and start working on a visual identity manual and source files.

They need to send the material they have and make a professional illustrator to redraw the logo, and then prepare the proper file formats to be distributed. EPS is probably not one of them.